# DataGrid ItemSource bound to selected item within another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following Data Structures:

```
List<Customer> currentCustomers {...}

public class Customer 
{
    public string ID { get, set }
    public string Name { get, set } 
    [...]
    public List<Products> { get, set } 
}
```

I have a customers DataGrid bound to the `currentCustomers` List. 
What I would like to be able to do is bind a second DataGrid to the selected item within customers to display all the Product information for that Customer.

i.e. The user clicks on a Customer within the Customers DataGrid, this then automatically updates a second DataGrid based on that Customers Products.

Is this even possible?

If so, is there a resource around that will tell/show me how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind it to [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customersList" CanSelectMultipleItems="false" ... />

<DataGrid x:Name="customerDetails" 
          ItemsSource = "{Binding ElementName = customersList, 
                                  Path = SelectedItem.Products}">
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="one"></DataGrid>
<DataGrid x:Name="two" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=one, Path=SelectedItem.Products}"></DataGrid>
```